# Limit of a difference of integrals that both look almost identical,

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

Let $\gamma (t) = t+i(e^t-1)$ for $-1\le t \le 1$.

find

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left[\int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin(z)}{(z-i\epsilon)^2} dz - \int_{\gamma} \frac{\sin(z)}{(z+i\epsilon)^2} dz\right]$$

I have tried using directly the parametrization given and integrating from -1 to 1 against $dt$.  Also, instead of sin(z), I used $e^{iz}$, and planned to take the imaginary part of the result.  No luck...

I then integrated by parts -- also not insightful.

Now I'm wondering whether dominated convergence theorem can be applied.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Note: The imaging part of $e^{iz}$ is not $\sin z$ in general. Indeed, $\sin z$ isn't real for most $z$.

Comment: Ah, right -- agreed @thomasandrews.  Usually we show that the integration over the parts of a contour not on the real axis is zero, so the problem reduces to integration over the real line and then taking real and imaginary parts make sense.  This problem statement is completely different ... hmm...

Comment: The usual trick would be to find some way to see this as almost a loop integral around a function. My initial attempts have failed, but this is what this looks like - following the curve below zero, then tracing back above zero, just missing the tiny connector which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A very rough outline.)

Write $\gamma_{\epsilon}(t)=\gamma(t)-i\epsilon$. Then the above is:

$$\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{\sin (z+i\epsilon)}{z^2}dz - \int_{\gamma_{-\epsilon}} \frac{\sin (z-i\epsilon)}{z^2}dz$$

Replacing with $\sin(a+b)$ formula, we get:

$$\cos(i\epsilon)\left(\left(\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}-\int_{\gamma_{-\epsilon}}\right)\frac{\sin z}{z^2}dz\right)+\\\sin(i\epsilon)
\left(\left(\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}+\int_{\gamma_{-\epsilon}}\right)\frac{\cos z}{z^2}\,dz\right)$$

The first part is "almost" a loop around zero, counter-clockwise, with the parts missing approaching zero when $\epsilon\to 0^+$. So the limit is actually the integral $$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{\sin z}{z^2}\,dz$$
for $\Gamma$ a loop around zero clockwise. This is just $2\pi i$, if I remember that step.

I suspect you can use that $\frac{\cos z}{z^2}$ is even to bound the integrals in the second part. Basically, for even functions:

$$\int_{\gamma_{-\epsilon}} =-\int_{-\gamma_{-\epsilon}}$$

So:

$$\left(\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}+\int_{\gamma_{-\epsilon}}\right)\frac{\cos z}{z^2}\,dz =\left(\int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}}-\int_{-\gamma_{-\epsilon}}\right)\frac{\cos z}{z^2}\,dz$$

These two paths, $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ and $-\gamma_{-\epsilon}$ are now both on the same side of $0$, and we can connect their endpoints with curves bounded away from zero, to show that these integral are bounded, and thus this term approaches zero when multiplied by $\sin(i\epsilon)$.

So the final result is, I believe, $2\pi i$.

Comment: Hi @ThomasAndrews, thanks so much for your answer.  This problem statement is a bit out of my reach, at the moment, even after considering your solution.  So, I think that I will move on for now and revisit this problem in a few days.  Have a great night :-)